# vb.net-mysql - many connections from many computers with the same user and password?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection

I'm working on a vb.net application connecting to mysql db which will have alot of users using it.

How should I deal with the user registration?

I mean, I used to create a table with a username and password fields to store the users data in it, but in this case all the users will connect to the database with the same username and password of the server (in the connection string)

I need a pointer on how to do this thing right...

What would happen if many connections established from many computers with the same user and password in the connection string?

Query results conflict or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open users on mysql (Privileges tab in phpmyadmin) and prompt each user for username and password upon application startup. Then you append user & password to mysql your connection string

As far as mysql is concerned, I think it doesn't care if one user is connected one time or N times.

Typical web app scenarios support this.